# VSTS Pull request doesn't trigger build

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I had this working up till last week, but now it's not. I have a build policy on my `develop` branch. It executes a build definition automatically when a pull request is created. The build runs on a hosted agent.

It was working, but now I need to manually trigger the build when I create a PR. I tried enabling then disabling. Also tried deleting and re-creating the policy. Neither worked.

Am I missing something? Has something changed in VSTS?

Screenshot of build policy:
[image]

Comment: What's the scenario when you found the build not triggered? Did you create a create PR to merge into develop branch or did you just a a comment (or else) for an existing PR?

Comment: Is your repo hosted in VSTS or somewhere else?

Comment: @Marina - Same process when it worked, and when it didn't. Before, creating a new PR to merge into develop and pushing a new commit to an existing PR triggered the build. Now neither trigger the build.

Comment: @Brian - Repo is hosted in VSTS.

Comment: @nthpixel Can you share the screen shot for how the build validation policy you configured?

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT I added a screenshot of the build policy.

Comment: @nthpixel  For your situation, you need to change Build expiration as Immediately when develop is updated. And I added details in my answer, you can have a try.

Answer (score 1):

For the PR build validation does not triggered immediately after pushing changes to the source branch, is caused by the Build expiration set with **After 12 hours if develop has been uploaded**.

That means, build will not be triggered immediately when source branch update. More details about [build expiration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/branch-policies?view=vsts#build-validation) as below:

> Set a build expiration to make sure that updates to your protected
> branch don't break changes in open pull requests.
>
> - **Immediately when
>   branch name is updated:** This option sets the build policy status in a
>   pull request to failed when the protected branch is updated. You must
>   requeue a build to refresh the build status. This setting ensures that
>   the changes in pull requests build successfully even as the protected
>   branch changes. This option is best for teams that have important
>   branches with a lower volume of changes. Teams working in busy
>   development branches may find it disruptive to wait for a build to
>   complete every time the protected branch is updated.
> - **After n hours
>   if branch name has been updated:** This option expires the current
>   policy status when the protected branch updates if the passing build
>   is older than the threshold entered. This option is a compromise
>   between always requiring a build when the protected branch updates and
>   never requiring one. This choice is excellent for reducing the number
>   of builds when your protected branch has frequent updates.
> - **Never:**
>   Updates to the protected branch do not change the policy status. This
>   reduces the number of builds for your branch, but can cause problems
>   when closing pull requests that haven't been updated recently.

So if you want the build triggered immediately after PR updated, you should change the Build expiration as **Immediately when develop is updated**.

[image]

Comment: I set it expire immediately but the build is still not automatically triggered.

Comment: Can you double check by setting PR build validation policy on a different branch?